# Firebase vs CloudKit Target Store Options

Tags: ios, firebase, google-play, app-store, cloudkit

I'm currently making an app using Swift. It's an app similar to those of restaurant rating apps where users rate restaurants and leave comments. I have two questions.

1) Is it possible to launch my app on both Google Play Store and App Store if I choose to store my servers on CloudKit? If yes, which one is easier to integrate into my app?

2) If I choose to use Firebase, since I'm using Swift as my coding language, can I still launch my app on both Google Play Store and App Store?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically anything "____kit" from Apple is a framework that's exclusive to the App Store. The features from SiriKit or HealthKit certainly cannot be launched on the Google Play Store.

If you're trying to deploy on both iOS and Android, I'd definitely choose Firebase. I use it myself on an app my company is creating, and have had no problems so far. It's owned by Google so you'll get great support on both iOS and Android.

Firebase is probably more powerful as well due to its connections into Google Cloud and Cloud Functions.

Hope that helped!